# Are these spaces homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topological spaces given by the sets$$ X = ( \mathbb{Q} \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x < 0 \} ) $$ $$ Y = X \cup \{ 0 \} $$ with the trace topology of the real line.

Are those spaces homeomorphic? If so, can you write an explicit homeomorphism between them?

Comment: Yes, they are. All countable metric spaces without isolated points are homeomorphic. See http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf for proofs.

Comment: Glad to help. It's not a complete answer as I have no explicit homeomorphism yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henno Brandsma noted in the comments, this is a consequence of a much more general fact. What follows is the closest that I’ve been able to come to an explicit homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$. Part of it is quite nice, but part of it is explicit in principle but not usably so in practice.

Let $\alpha_0=-\sqrt2$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\alpha_n=2^{-n}\alpha_0$. Let $Q_0=(\leftarrow,\alpha_0)$, and for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $Q_n=\Bbb Q\cap(\alpha_{n-1},\alpha_n)$; each $Q_n$ is clopen in $X$ and $Y$, and $X$ is the disjoint union of the sets $Q_n$.

Let

$$Z=Q_0\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\frac{2^n}3Q_{2n-1}\cup\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(-\frac{2^n}3\right)Q_{2n}\;;\tag{1}$$

a little thought shows that

$$Z=Q_0\cup\left(\Bbb Q\cap\left(\frac23\alpha_0,-\frac13\alpha_0\right)\right)\;.$$

Moreover, the from the description of $Z$ in $(1)$ we can easily produce the homeomorphism

$$h:Y\to Z:y\mapsto\begin{cases}
y,&\text{if }y\in Q_0\cup\{0\}\\\\
\dfrac{2^n}3y,&\text{if }y\in Q_{2n-1}\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb Z^+\\\\
-\dfrac{2^n}3y,&\text{if }y\in Q_{2n}\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb Z^+\;.
\end{cases}$$

Finding an explicit homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ now reduces to finding one between $\Bbb Q\cap(\alpha_0,0)$ and $\Bbb Q\cap\left(\frac23\alpha_0,-\frac13\alpha_0\right)$.

In principle this is possible. The [Calkin-Wilf sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree#Breadth_first_traversal) is an explicit enumeration of the positive rationals, and from that it’s easy to get an explicit enumeration of all the rationals. Then we can apply the [back-and-forth construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method#Application_to_densely_ordered_sets) to the two intervals of rationals to get an order-isomorphism, which is necessarily also a homeomorphism. This construction is also explicit, but it’s obviously not usably explicit in the way that the map $h$ above is. Unfortunately, I don’t at the moment see anything better.